# Activate Lightning Record Page via Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, flexipages

I can deploy Lightning Pages, aka Flexi Pages with the Metadata API. In order to active a Lightning Page, I can do so in the Page-Builder via `Setup-Home -> Object Manager -> Account -> Lightning Record Pages`. But howto do this with the Metadata API? I would assume, that this configuration is also stored in the `CustomObject` of the `Account` but after downloading it, I couldn't find such an entry and there is also no documentation of such a thing [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm).

So: How can I active a Lightning Record Page with the API?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and spent quite a lot of time to find the solution. Unfortunately, there are nothing about ability to activate Lightning record page via API. So it turns out that we have only Lightning App Builder for now to do this. 
Finally I left post at [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cLetQAE). Hope Salesforce could offer any solution in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this was possible at the time you wrote this post but it now is and can be achieved by using the following in an applications/AppName.app metadata file:

```
<profileActionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <content>PageName</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <pageOrSobjectType>Account</pageOrSobjectType>
    <recordType>Account.RecordType</recordType>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
    <profile>ProfileName</profile>
</profileActionOverrides>
```

Comment: Thoughts on how to get this to work for the home page?  It works for other pages for me, thank you!