# How can I activate a Lightning Page via metadata?

Tags: metadata-api, lightning, tooling-api

I am deploying a solution which includes Lightning Pages and I would like to programmatically activate the FlexiPage in the target org when it is deployed.

In the [Configure Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages.htm) documentation it describes Activation on Save or performed later using the Activation button.

1. Is it possible to programmatically activate a Lightning Page as the default for an object or must it be activated manually after deployment?
2. Where is the default Lightning Page per object stored in metadata?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

> [This] can be achieved by using the following in an
>   applications/AppName.app metadata file:
>
> ```
> <profileActionOverrides>
>     <actionName>View</actionName>
>     <content>PageName</content>
>     <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
>     <pageOrSobjectType>Account</pageOrSobjectType>
>     <recordType>Account.RecordType</recordType>
>     <type>Flexipage</type>
>     <profile>ProfileName</profile>
> </profileActionOverrides>
> ```

Courtesy of Stephen Titley, https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cLetQAE

And also this article: [Activate Lightning Record Page via Metadata API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130246/activate-lightning-record-page-via-metadata-api/134087)

The [docs say "The only valid values are record-home and standard-home"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profileactionoverride.htm) for `<pageOrSobjectType>`. You can put an sObject in there; if you haven't sub-classed record type (you are using master) you can just remove the `<recordType />` element.