# Set Home Flexipage as Org Default via the API

Tags: json, metadata-api, page-layout, unmanaged-package, flexipages

I have a new Lightning Home Page that I would like to push out to my customers and set it automatically as the Org Default via the metadata API. [Salesforce documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) makes it sound like its a possibility by setting the sObjectType as null but its not working. So I am wondering now if its even possible to set the home page as a default programmatically. Any thoughts?

```
{
actionName: "View",
comment:
  "Action override updated by Lightning App Builder during activation.",
content: "My_New_Home_Page_Layout",
formFactor: "Large",
skipRecordTypeSelect: "false",
type: "Flexipage",
pageOrSobjectType: "null",
},
```

Comment: Does [How to set org wide default home page through metadata api? Not for specific app or profiles](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272046/how-to-set-org-wide-default-home-page-through-metadata-api-not-for-specific-app) help?